# inserting an extra character in a varchar2 string in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose I have a string `abc/bcg/ghy/`. Now I want to insert an extra `/` character wherever I find one '/' in the string....
the output should be like---

```
abc//bcg//ghy
```

how can I do it? I have already tried `REGEXP` and `STRING` functions...but couldn't get the desired...

Answer (score 3):

Try `replace`:

```
REPLACE('abc/bcg/ghy/', '/', '//')
```